# BotFramework: Can you branch off to several possible dialogs from the mainDialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dialog, botframework, chatbot

I'm making a multi dialog chatbot with the MS Bot framework in c# and visual studio.

I have a main dialog file that should branch off to two possible further dialog files depending on what the user enters.

[image]

However I can't seem to be able to branch off successfully to both dialogs and now I'm doubting whether it's possible?

Here is my code , note that I use the BeginDialogAsync Method to switch between files. It works for the first dialog (vpn), but not the second (sauvegarde).

I am thinking it is because you have to go from one dialog to another and cannot do multiple branches from one class? I can't find any explanation in the documentation.

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> MiddleStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (((string)stepContext.Result).ToLower().Contains("vpn"))
    {
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Ah d'accord", InputHints.ExpectingInput)); //tr: oh ok 

        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"{(string)stepContext.Result} ? Il me semble que votre problème est lié a votre vpn..."), cancellationToken); // it seems your problem is linked with your vpn

        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Vous n'arrivez pas à vous connecter à distance? Je vais vous poser quelques questions afin de mieux vous aider à résoudre ce problème."), cancellationToken); // tr: i will ask you some questions 
        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync((nameof(VPNDialog)), null, cancellationToken);

    }
    else if (((string)stepContext.Result).ToLower().Contains("sauvegard"))
    {
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"{(string)stepContext.Result} ? Il me semble que votre problème est lié a la sauvegarde de vos données..."), cancellationToken); // oh it seems your problem is to do with saving your data

        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync((nameof(SauvegardeDialog)), null, cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Je ne crois pas pouvoir règler ce problème, entrer n'importe quoi pour revenir au menu principale où vous pourriez reformulez votre demande. ", InputHints.ExpectingInput)); //I don't think I can solve your problem sorry
        return await stepContext.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I have also added the dialogs like so at the top of the main dialog class

```
AddDialog(new SauvegardeDialog(userState)); 
AddDialog(new VPNDialog(userState));
```

Is there some little part that I'm missing somewhere??
here are some sample conversations:

Success:

[image]

Fail:

[image]

I would appreciate any help! thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your SauvegardeDialog please, it seems the problem is from there

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I changed the namespace in the SauvgardeDialog file from

```
namespace MultiTurnPromptDialog.Dialogs
```

to

```
namespace Microsoft.Dialogs
```

I don't really understand why